# Ruby on Rails: proper method of validating Model data comparing with parameter(s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

Using rails version 4.0.5 currently. I can't seem to find a canonical answer to whether this is the best (DRY, MVC, etc.) method to validate what seems to me to be a simple validation. In my model, I have a unique `document_id`. This `document_id` should appear in the filename (in this case, always xml files) e.g. `blah/blah.document_id.xml` and it should also appear as an attribute on the root element of the xml document e.g. `id='document_id'`. I'd like to write (assuming the `document_id` and `filename` don't match):

```
doc = Document.new
...
if !doc.valid?
    puts doc.errors[:document_id] # <= 'document_id does not match filename'
end
```

Here's the closest I've gotten:

```
doc = Document.new
...
if !doc.valid?
    ... # no error caught here
end
if doc.document_id_matches_filename(xml_file)
    puts 'document_id does not match filename'
end
```

Inside app/models/document.rb, I have this:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    def document_id_matches_filename(filename)
        return self.document_id == File.basename(filename, '.xml')
    end
end
```

I could add a `filename` column to the `Document` model and use `doc.valid` with a custom validator, but I don't want to effectively store the `document_id` twice. I can find information on sending parameters to custom validators or creating Validation classes, but those all seem to do things like use `Time.now` or things like that -- dynamic information but not specific information related to the document. I could try to find the xml file based on the doc id in a custom validator, but my rake task or Controller already has this information, it just needs to hand it off to the Model to validate against. Theoretically this would either be a rake task or on the Controller, I can't imagine that mattering.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a virtual attribute to store the filename so your model has access?

Something like...

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :filename

  validate :document_id_matches_filename

  private

  def document_id_matches_filename
    errors.add(:document_id, 'does not match filename') unless self.document_id == File.basename(self.filename, '.xml')
  end
end
```

That allows you to use ActiveModel's validations and get the error message you're looking for and encapsulate it all within the model without having to add an extra DB column.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly the approach I was looking for. I looked over virtual attributes a number of times and it never clicked with me, but that's perfect.

Comment: A small addition that was not really in my original question, I've chosen to do this:

    `errors.add(:document_id, 'does not match filename') unless self.filename.nil? or self.document_id == File.basename(self.filename, '.xml')`

In this way, I can still get `doc.valid?` to work if I pull from the database--presumably if the document is in the database it has already passed this check previously, but `self.filename` won't be set.